# Turn off syntax highlighting in Markdown code blocks (highlight.js underneath)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, marp, highlight.js

I am doing a presentation using [Marp](https://github.com/yhatt/marp). It automatically adds syntax coloring to blocks of code. For example this would be colored as Ruby:

````
```
def fun(x):
    x+1
end
```
````

I can force highlight.js to change the syntax highlighting like this:

````
```python
def fun(x):
    x+1
end
```
````

Is there a keyword which disables highlighting (something like *none*, *default*, *code* or *unknown*)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/yhatt/marp/issues/81#issuecomment-241957649) it is possible and the keyword is ***text***:

````
```text
def fun(x):
    x+1
end
```
````

Answer (score 10):

I found only ***plaintext*** to work:

````
```plaintext
def fun(x):
    x+1
end
```
````

Source: https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/

Comment: The link is broken.